# Does anyone know what it is in my apple cider vinegar?

Tags: vinegar

I bought it in December. Is it spoiled? I hadn't noticed that until today. The smell is normal.

⠀⠀⠀
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mass in your picture is [the mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_of_vinegar) - cellulose and bacteria that convert the cider into vinegar.  It may not have been there when you bought it, but can develop over time.  It's safe to consume, but you can filter it out with filter paper if you want.